# Query about definition of $C^k$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Definition of $C^k(R^m)$ as given in Rudin is which consists of all functions from $R^k$ to R such that all partial derivative of order k exist and continuous.

Is it equivalent to k^{th} total derivative exist and contiuous?

Comment: The short answer is yes.

Comment: I was expecting that. @JackyChong. Can you atleast give some reference for long answer